# Add-Content infinite loop

Tags: powershell, infinite-loop

I have an old piece of PowerShell script that uses `Add-Content` in a `for` loop to write data to a file and it works fine when run locally on a PC's C: drive.

I've now been asked to relocate the script and files to a QNAP folder share (not sure if this has anything to do with the problem).

Now when the script runs from the share, the `for` loop runs infinitely - you can see the file size increasing and check the row count once you break out of the program.

It doesn't seem to matter if I use UNC or drive mapping the infinite looping still occurs.

Here is the script block:

```cs
####################
# Define Variables #
####################
$Source = 'G:\Label_Spreadsheets\' + $textbox1.Text + '.csv'
$Target = 'G:\Label_Spreadsheets\labels.csv'
$EndNum = ($LastUsedNumber + $numericupdown1.Value)

######################
# Create Source File #
######################

#######################
# Add CSV Header rows #
#######################
Add-Content $Source "Stock Code,Filter#,ProductionOrder#,SalesOrder#,Compatability";

#####################
# Add specific Rows # 
#####################
for ($i = $StartNum; $i -le $EndNum; $i++) {
    $line = $combobox1.SelectedItem + ',' + $i + ',' + $textbox1.Text + ',' + $textbox2.Text + ','
    Add-Content $Source $line
}
```

I wondered if it was a known provider problem (as shown at [this URL](https://powershell.org/2014/02/20/powershell-gotcha-unc-paths-and-providers/)) but trying these did not resolve the issue.

And yes I know it's writing a CSV - like I said: old script.

Comment: `$i` is a counter, and the loop ends when it passes `$EndNum`. And that's coming from `$LastUsedNumber` and `$numericupdown`. Where are they coming from? What are their values?

Comment: @TessellilatingHeckler - $LastUsedNumber is a value read from a file (the previous serial number).    $numericupdown  is from a numeric dialog box.        As stated the code works fine locally - the loop breaks at the correct point and program closes. But when put on UNC or Mapped drive this loop doesn't break - very odd.

Comment: This should have nothing to do with where your files or scripts end up. A loop doesn't terminate if its condition is never satisfied -- that means it is never the case that, starting from `$StartNum` and incrementing by one, we eventually reach `$EndNum` (or the difference is so high that it just takes much longer than you expect). Print the contents of these variables before the loop. It's certainly possible for the script to behave differently depending on its location, but then that's because of code we're not seeing here.

Comment: Presumably somewhere else in your code, it's reading from a relative path. I can't quite imagine how, even if they were reading as $null, you can still increment `$i` from null upwards and then the loop would terminate.